# String ASCII value to Integer Array

Tags: vb.net

i want to convert a string to a integer array.
but i want the ASCII Value in the integer array

for example "A"  -> 65

for example "2"  -> 50

`Dim myString as string = "ABC"`

'....

Dim integerArray(3) as integer

plz without any work around like loops ;)

Comment: There will always be some loop, even if you don't see it because it is inside some method. So, a method that contains a loop will be a suitable solution for you? Also: Loops are not workarounds, they are straightforward. Replacing a loop with something non-straightforward can be considered a workaround, though.

Comment: Also in .net strings are represented as unicode which may contain values that do not have an ascii representation, how should the solution handle them?

Comment: true, use this functioncs loops...   you can get the ASCII sign, or his value is not the same... ASCII sign "2" has the value 50

Comment: What about ⋍ which has no valid ascii encoding but is valid in a .net string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ASCII encoding, you can do this:

```
Dim test As String = "Hello"
Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test)
```

The array 'bytes' will contain the ASCII representation of the string.  As @user1937198 pointed out, though, is ASCII encoding what you really want?

To get the byte array to an array of integers, you can do this:

```
Dim ints As Integer() = bytes.Select(Function(b) Convert.ToInt32(b)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any "cheating" like for loops:

```
Dim asciiValues = "The string to convert".ToCharArray().Select(Function(c) Asc(c)).ToArray()
```

(Note: loops are not cheating either... ;))